# launching a watchOS app on real watch with debugger initializes twice

Tags: swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am starting an app from XCode 7.1.1 on my real Apple Watch (watchOS 2.0.1)

some of the code in my ExtensionDelegate:

```
var applicationDidFinishLaunchingCalled = 0
func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
    applicationDidFinishLaunchingCalled++
    print("applicationDidFinishLaunching() round \(applicationDidFinishLaunchingCalled)")

}

var applicationDidBecomeActiveCalled = 0
func applicationDidBecomeActive() {
    applicationDidBecomeActiveCalled++
     print("applicationDidBecomeActive() round \(applicationDidBecomeActiveCalled)")

}

var applicationWillResignActiveCalled = 0
func applicationWillResignActive() {
    applicationWillResignActiveCalled++
    print("applicationWillResignActive() round \(applicationWillResignActiveCalled)")

}
```

which prints the following into the console:

```
applicationDidFinishLaunching() round 1
applicationDidBecomeActive() round 1
applicationDidFinishLaunching() round 2
applicationDidBecomeActive() round 2
```

(no call of applicationWillResignActive())

What is happening here? 
How can I prevent that the app is initialized twice?
How do I know that this is not happening when I'm not debugging?

I don't have this effect in the simulator where everything is called once.

Comment: Does this happen for any other app? Have you tried restarting the Mac and the watch?  I have seen my app appear to load on my watch then "blink" and begin to load again, after which it is running/debugging correctly. This usually happens later in the day and a reset cleans things up.